# Python Program to rotate a complex no by 180

Tags: python, algebra

I want to rotate a complex no by 180° and this code is in my textbook but it gives me a error everytime

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = 2 + 4j
plt.scatter (x.real, x.imag, color='red')
plt.scatter (-1 x.real, -1 x.imag, color = 'blue')
plt.show ()
```

Desired Output
[I want output something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GFCA.jpg)

Comment: What is the error it gives you? You should include the traceback so we can explain it to you what it is trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either -

```
plt.scatter (-1 * x.real, -1 * x.imag, color = 'blue')
```

or simply -

```
plt.scatter (-x.real, -x.imag, color = 'blue')
```